# Android New Project : Asking for login

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin

Created Newly android application in vs 2012.
Firstly it asks for login with subscribed username & password.
But after login, it shows message.
"Your Xamarin account does not include support for vs 2012, please download vs 2015, which include xamarin support for all"

I just want to use xamarin in visual studio 2012.
Please Guide me.

Comment: This is not the place for questions like this, try http://superuser.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it related to software licensing

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 support requires a legacy Xamarin Business / Enterprise license or one of the new Visual Studio / MSDN licenses.

The Community edition of Xamarin can be used with any non-express version of Visual Studio 2013 or any version of Visual Studio 2015.